# How to disable SEF pagination of Joomla's VirtueMart component?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart, sef, joomla-sef-urls

Is it possible to disable SEF for VirtueMart component? I don't need if for some reasons on pagination...

BUT, I need to disable it ONLY on pagination. For other link on VM I need pagination.

Is it possible to do that with small changes in code?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to try expanding your question with some detail.

Comment: Sure. On my Joomla site I have VirtueMart component installed. Since Joomla is configured with enabled SEF, all of the links are "rewrited" to be more SEF. What I need is not to have rewritten links in VirtueMart's pagination, but to have them on all other pages (together with all of the other links in VirtueMart).

Comment: What do you mean by VM's pagination - are you talking about product category listings, specials, search results...

Answer (score 0):

First I`d suggest you update your joomla version ASAP, because there was some security bug fixed on latest version.

As for your problem, please make sure you are using default joomla .htaccess and also go to sh404sef configuration at "By component" tab and set Virtuemart component ( in 4th dropdown box ) to "Use joomla! router.php". After that go to "URL manager" delete the old virtuemart sef urls and let the changes to be applied.

Install Instructions

1. Download the [router.php](http://paulmason.name/media/uploads/blog/virtuemart-sef/virtuemart-sef-router.zip) file
2. Place the [router.php](http://paulmason.name/media/uploads/blog/virtuemart-sef/virtuemart-sef-router.zip) file into your components/com_virtuemart folder in your joomla installation.
   [image]
3. Enable Joomla SEF URLs in your Joomla admin under Global Configuration-> Site -> SEO Settings as shown in the image below:

[image]

Features

1) SEF URLS for all important landing pages (products, categories and manufactures)

2) Handles categories and products with the same name

3) Converts / characters to - in URL

4) Handles multiple categories for one product by choosing the category with the highest list order

5) No duplicate URLs